# php reverse email from right to left

Tags: php, string, reverse

i have email : ue.aporue.lraporue@otlatnom-dratta.nhoj

and i want it like:

john.attard-montalto@europarl.europa.eu

when i use `revWords('ue.aporue.lraporue@otlatnom-dratta.nhoj');` i get:

eu.europa.europarl@montalto-attard.john

```
function revWords($string) {
    //We need to find word boundries
    $wordChars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $buffer = '';
    $return = '';
    $len = strlen($string);
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $len) {
        $chr = $string[$i];
        if (($chr & 0xC0) == 0xC0) {
            //UTF8 Characer!
            if (($chr & 0xF0) == 0xF0) {
                //4 Byte Sequence
                $chr .= substr($string, $i + 1, 3);
                $i += 3;
            } elseif (($chr & 0xE0) == 0xE0) {
                //3 Byte Sequence
                $chr .= substr($string, $i + 1, 2);
                $i += 2;
            } else {
                //2 Byte Sequence
                $i++;
                $chr .= $string[$i];
            }
        }
        if (stripos($wordChars, $chr) !== false) {
            $buffer = $chr . $buffer;
        } else {
            $return .= $buffer . $chr;
            $buffer = '';
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $return . $buffer;
}
```

can someone help me thanks

Comment: Now I understand why reversing string task is so often on job interviews

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not [strrev](http://php.net/strrev) ?

```
echo strrev("ue.aporue.lraporue@otlatnom-dratta.nhoj");
```

Answer (score 5):

PHP has a built in function to reverse strings:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

Whats wrong with using

```
//strrev ( string $string )

echo strrev('ue.aporue.lraporue@otlatnom-dratta.nhoj');

//Returns john.attard-montalto@europarl.europa.eu
```